# Checking the package.json version number on new Pull Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

Is there any way to check the version number in package.json to make sure it was changed as part of the pull request requirements?

Comment: You can use a git pre-push hook to check for that and prevent the push if it hasn't been changed.

Comment: This sounds like what I want, have to learn how to do that then

Comment: They're bash files which I don't have a lot of experience with but there should be a few resources out there that can help you. Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

The `package.json` file will have its own version number which you can look out for in a among the commits in a PR.

Whether you can reject a PR automatically if the version hasn't been updated, though, I'm not sure; but it's certainly visible to anyone with access to view PRs on a repo.

[image]

Comment: I'm asking more about being able to prevent a PR from being merged if the version number of the package itself isn't updated in the package.json, not for dependencies.

Comment: Ah, I get you you -- my bad. Updated answer. Does that help?